# How to swap values in addresses in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I am trying to create random data and sort them into ascending order using the [bubble sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Firstly I am creating random data and then passing them into the bubble function which then has the swap function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define N 5

void swap(int *first, int *second)
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = *ptr;
}

void bubble(int A[], int length) {
  int n; /* The number of algorithm passes */
  int a;
  int b;
  int *ptr;
  n = length - 1;
  for (a=0; a<=n; a++) {
    for (b=n; b>a; b--) {
        if(A[b-1]>A[b])
        {
        swap(&A[b-1], &A[b]);
        }
    }
  }
}

void print_int_array(int a[], int length) {
  int i;

    for (i=0; i<length; i++ )
    {
      printf("a[%d]=%3d, ",i,a[i]);
    }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
  int i;
  int data[N];

  /* Create random data */
  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    data[i] = (int) ((rand()+0.5)/(double) RAND_MAX * 999);
  }

  print_int_array(data,N); /* Print original random dataset */

  bubble(data,N);
  printf("Data is now sorted:\n"); /* Print sorted data */

  print_int_array(data,N);

  return 0;
}
```

I understand that the swap function should have this instead:

```
void swap(int *first,int *second)
{
    int temp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
}
```

But how is this different to the original swap function I have created?

When I run the code with the original code I get the result:

```
a[0]=  1, a[1]=563, a[2]=193, a[3]=807, a[4]=584, a[5]=479,

Data is now sorted:
a[0]=  1, a[1]=193, a[2]=193, a[3]=479, a[4]=479, a[5]=479,
```

The second array does not seem to show it has sorted out. The problem arises in the swap function and for some reason the last few elements have the same value and have not been swapped.

Comment: You are assigning the pointer first to ptr, then you change the value at the address, to which first points. However, ptr also points to that memory. You are not swapping anything.

Comment: The other swap you stated stores the value at the memory, to which first points, in temp, not the pointer

Comment: This would also work: *first = *first ^ *second; *second = *first ^ *second; *first = *first ^ *second;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original swap function, you're overwriting the data that `first` points to. Saving the pointer in another variable doesn't save the original data anywhere. So when you do

```
*second = *ptr;
```

`ptr` points to the same memory that `first` points to, so this is no different from

```
*second = *first;
```

Since you already copied from `*second` to `*first` on the previous line, you're simply copying that back to `*second`. The final result is then that both locations contain what `*second*` originally contained.

Comment: Ahh I understand now, my initial thoughts was to be able to switch the addresses of the values. How would you write it so that you can swap the values using addresses rather than pointers? And if you switch addresses would that also affect the for loop since it needs to check the memory addresses of the last element first

Comment: Your `swap` function would need to take `int **` arguments instead of `int*`. And you would have to be sorting an array of pointers, not an array of integers.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when you alter `*first`, that also alters `*ptr`.

```
void swap(int *first, int *second)
{
    int *ptr; // say that *first is 2 and *second is 1
    ptr = first; // ptr points to the same memory as first
    *first = *second; // now *first and *ptr is 1
    *second = *ptr; // *second doesn't change as intended, and is still 1
}
```